# How to limit execution time of services with Weblogic/Blazeds/Spring

Tags: apache-flex, spring, service, weblogic, blazeds

I'm working on a project where we use Flex, Spring, Hibernate and Blazeds, all working on a Weblogic server.

Everything works fine and we call services at the server side from the flex app without problems, but now we need to limit the time who spent the execution of the services to 2 seconds, if any service takes more than 2 seconds the server must return a timeout to the flex app.

I've been searching for a way to do this with the blazeds configuration, but it looks that it's not possible.

¿Is there any way to achieve this? I've thought in add a filter to the blazeds requests so it can control the timeout... But I can't find any example and I don't have enough knowledge of filters.

¿Could you help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing, but would this be a property of the Java engine that Blaze is running in?  Perhaps you should look for a WebLogic setting?

Comment: I'm looking the weblogic settings, but i can't find anything. Mostly because i only need to limit the time of the services who goes trough blazeds, there are another services who can be called in other ways and that don't need the timeout restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can set the timeout on RemoteObject OR Webservice.. whatever you are using. Once the specified timeout happens, it will throw a FaultEvent, which is when you supposed to take an appropriate action like for RemoteObject's use their channel's disconnect and so..
Look at this post:
[Flex RemoteObject timeouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601404/flex-remoteobject-timeouts)